# Disallow commented out properties within object literals

Tags: javascript, eslint

We have code like this in our codebase:

```
  return {
    props: {
      categoryId: productCategoryId,
      query: context.query,
      data,
      error: error ? error : false,
      // resources,
      locale,
    },
  };
```

How can I disallow commented out properties like that? Is there a way to disable single line comments and always require multiline star block comments?

The problem is commenting out object properties which aren't needed anymore instead of deleting them, leaving unneeded comments in the codebase. There's no reason to comment out a property. We have versioning. If it's not needed it should be deleted.

Of course it's valid to put explanatory comments in objects so this might be difficult to distinguis. Requiring `/* */` would at least discourage pressing Ctrl + # to remove properties from objects.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the body, it's not clear what the problem with that is. You can prefer `/*` for multiple lines with e.g. https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/multiline-comment-style

Comment: What's wrong with putting a comment in an object literal? Seems like an overly-draconian rule to me.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler ah fair enough, that makes more sense. I don't believe a linter would be able to differentiate between a commented out property and a valid descriptive comment though. Manual code reviews would help

Comment: Fundamentally the linter can't differentiate between what you _did_ and what you _meant_. Even if you could enable such a rule, it would likely just get auto-fixed to `/* resources, */` instead. This (both the inappropriate coding _and_ missing it in review) is the kind of people problem it's hard to fix by just adding a rule.

Comment: What you describe as a problem should be handled at the code-review stage. Not as a lint rule. *At worst* I'd consider it at a warning level but nothing more. Which would also mean that if it gets enabled as a warning, I'd also expect valid usages to be marked to not produce warnings. Which, in turn, tends to be more noisy than just good code hygiene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sure way to detect *commented out properties* with the linter. Consider the following:

```javascript
const obj = {
    foo: "hello",
    //required
    bar: "world"
}
```

Does this mean that the comment says `bar` is required? Or did the code originally include a `required` property:

```javascript
//presumably somewhere in scope there is something like:
const required = true;

const obj = {
    foo: "hello",
    required
}
```

This cannot be determined by the linter.

---

At most a [a custom rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rules) can attempt to detect such commented out properties. See [the tutorial from ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rule-tutorial). Such a rule can try to *guess* whether a comment is or is not a commented out property presumably by checking if it *looks like* something that is valid or invalid within an object initialiser.

However, this is error-prone. For example the `//required` is potentially valid within an object literal. Yet it might just be communicating the word "required" to other developers, rather than being dead commented out code.

---

Overall, if developers are already leaving unneeded comments, a lint rule is unlikely to stop them. If you require that a multiline comment `/* */` is used, then they can simply use

```javascript
return {
    props: {
      categoryId: productCategoryId,
      query: context.query,
      data,
      error: error ? error : false,
      /* resources, */
      locale,
    },
};
```

Or even worse, take up even more vertical space:

```javascript
return {
    props: {
      categoryId: productCategoryId,
      query: context.query,
      data,
      error: error ? error : false,
      /* 
       * resources, 
       */
      locale,
    },
};
```

or make this syntactically invalid code for an object initialiser so a custom rule will not detect it as *possibly* commented out property:

```javascript
return {
    props: {
      categoryId: productCategoryId,
      query: context.query,
      data,
      error: error ? error : false,
      // ..resources, 
      locale,
    },
};
```

---

Overall, this is not an issue to solve via programming. It is a development culture problem. As such, it is best tackled via code reviews. Write down a set of coding guidelines and *make sure code reviews are done*. Then apply the style guide to all code reviews.

It is probably a good idea to sweep through some of the more common files and clean them up to use as an example of code that respects the guidelines. If possible, clean up the entire code base to conform. Then only new code going in can introduce undesired code. This is where code reviews should catch it.